# Extract specific elements from matrix

Tags: r, matrix, extract

Suppose I have a matrix

```
x <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1,
              1, 0, 0,
              0, 1, 0), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 3, 
            dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c")))
```

I now need two vectors (or even better tow columns in a data.frame) with the first vector/column holding the column name and the second vector holding the rowname for all those element in `x` that are 1.

So in my example I would like to get this

```
v1 <- c("a", "b", "b", "c")
v2 <- c("b", "a", "c", "a")
```

Whats the fastest and most elegant way to do this for a 20 x 20 matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use parameter `arr.ind` of which for that:

```
indices <- which(x==1, arr.ind=TRUE)
#  row col
#b   2   1
#a   1   2
#c   3   2
#a   1   3
```

Then you can just replace the row/column index with the name:

```
v1 <- rownames(x)[indices[, "row"]]
v2 <- colnames(x)[indices[, "col"]]
```

Comment: thanks, the `arr.ind` argument was new to me. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

and another solution using `row` and `column` functions:

```
ind <- (x == 1)
colnames(x)[col(x)[ind]]
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "c"
rownames(x)[row(x)[ind]]
#[1] "b" "a" "c" "a"
```

as to the speed of the two approaches, Cath's and mine:

```
cath <- function(){
  x <- matrix(0, ncol = 20, nrow = 20, dimnames = list(letters[1 : 
 20], letters[1 : 20]))
  x[sample(20 * 20, rpois(1, 50))] <- 1
  indices <- which(x == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
  list(v1 = rownames(x)[indices[, "row"]], v2 = colnames(x)[indices[, 
"col"]])
}


stas <- function(){
   x <- matrix(0, ncol = 20, nrow = 20, dimnames = list(letters[1 : 20], letters[1 : 20]))
   x[sample(20 * 20, rpois(1, 50))] <- 1
   ind <- (x == 1)
   list(v1 = colnames(x)[col(x)[ind]], v2 = rownames(x)[row(x)[ind]])
}

microbenchmark(cath, stas, times = 1000L)
# Unit: nanoseconds
# expr min lq   mean median uq  max neval
# cath  45 54 77.855   56.0 57 9718  1000
# stas  45 56 61.457   57.5 59 1831  1000
```

Cath's is slightly faster on average.

Comment: I like both answers. I will still accept Cath's answer since it is the faster one and the `which` functions is probably used more often. But Thanks for the analysis!

Comment: @ManuelS no probs :)